# Create ETL process in SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl

Suppose I've data from different sources. For example, MS SQL and Oracle. And these data are connected. And data from different sources should be loaded into 1 table. What are the ways in the SSIS to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'connected' ? You have different source in `data flow task` (like OLEDB) which can be used to pull data. Play around. you will figure it out

Comment: This is not the way to learn SSIS.   Take a class, read a book, do some tutorials on the web.   This question is too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use the [Merge Join](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-basics-using-the-merge-join-transformation/).

It allows to access data from two or more heterogeneous sources and join them by a common column/field (one or more of them).

The Merge Join will form a unified data stream which will be possible to direct to a single point of destination as a database table.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple solutions based on requirements and table structure.

1.Relational tables - [Merge join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/merge-join-transformation)

2.Merge common data set - [Union All](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/union-all-transformation)

You may study and implement various [Data Flow Transformations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/integration-services-transformations).